# UWP: Have page wait until user is done with a User Control

Tags: c#, user-controls, uwp

I am writing code that asks the user to select an employee and type in the employee's password before continuing their action. I made the Employee Selection segment a user control so I can attach the segment to the pages that needs it. I also would like the page to pause when the user control is up and to continue where it left off when the user has selected an employee. Is there are way to force the code the pause at any moment?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pausing the code"?  your question isn't clear.

Comment: If the user were to do an action like clicking a button that takes them to a new page, I want the user control to pop up and require the user to go through the control before they navigate to the new page. So I essentially want the code to wait until the user is done with the user control segment.

Comment: Then don't run the code in the constructor or on page load but run it after the user is done with your UserControl?

Comment: What code should not be in the constructor or page load? The UserControl's code or the code of the page that I am currently on? Also, how can I tell the code when the user is done with the UserControl?

Comment: before you redirect the page on user action(on_click()) , load the user control -> do whatever save operation you intend to do in the UC and then let the redirect happen. Without any sample code, that would be my best guess.

Comment: I have tried to load the UC before the navigating to the new page, and it just goes into the new page.

Comment: No, dont redirect in page_load(). do that once you are done whatever you want to do "in UC"

Comment: So I should do the Navigate call in the UC?

Comment: I don't think I am explaining my issue correctly. I have a page that has a UserControl attached to it and is collapsed so it's not visible at the moment. All the information that's on the UC should be loaded once the page it's attached to is loaded as well. What I want to happen is when the user does an event, like pushing a button, the UC becomes visible and forces the user to complete it before the remaining actions that are apart of the event happen. Is there a way to force the page to wait until the user is done completing whatever is on the UC?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a ContentDialog instead of UserControl, and it will block MainPage. But keep in mind that `await dialog.ShowAsync()`  won't block the UI.

If you need to "Pause" `OnNavigatedFrom()` event you can look on Template10 page events , they added possibility to wait untill job is finished then navigate from current page.

**EDIT**

You could also can add a flag into your usercontrol so you can add a check and cancel navigation from page untill `_myUserControl.CanNavigateFrom()`